SlimSelect input search in wire-element modal doesn't work
I am using SlimSelect (https://github.com/brianvoe/slim-select) in wire-element modal (https://github.com/wire-elements/modal).
but after opening SlimSelect, I can't click or type in the search box.
I thought the focus is not in the search box.
how to fix this problem?

<div>

    <form wire:submit.prevent="save" style="text-align: left !important;">
        <div class="mb-6" wire:ignore>
            <label for="manage" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                Manage <font color="red">*</font>
            </label>
            <select id="manage" wire:model.live="manage" x-init="new SlimSelect({select: '#manage'})" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500">
                <option value="" selected>Choose a manage</option>
                @if( $this->_manage->count() > 0 )
                @foreach( $this->_manage as $key => $value )
                <option value="{{ $value->hashid }}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
                @endif
            </select>
            @error('manage')
            <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600 dark:text-red-500">
                {{ $message }}
            </p>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </form>

</div>

